# Setting launch URL doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a button, when clicked executes the following code :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

This works fine on iPhone 5c (iOS 9.3.1) , iPad (iOS 9.3.2) **BUT** doesn't work on iPhone 4s(iOS 9.3.2). can any one tell what's wrong ??

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Are you launching the URL from the main app on the 4s? the **prefs** URL Scheme only works from Today Extensions.

Comment: @Armin it isn't giving any error ,this line gets executed and app stays in same screen, but it is supposed to go to settings.

Comment: yes I'm launching from main app.. and can you tell me more about extensions?